# React if statement in map inside JSX tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've the following function to build a tabbed items:

```
function ConstructTabs(props) {
  const tabs = props.tabs;
  const makeTabs = tabs.map((tab, index) => {
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        className="input-tabs"
        id={"tab" + index}
        type="radio"
        name="tabs"
        {index === 0 ? checked : ""}
      />
      <label for={"tab" + index}>{tab}</label>
    </React.Fragment>
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {makeTabs}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I want to insert the *checked* property only when the index is 0, my problem is with the condition *"{index === 0 ? checked : ""}"*. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

  275 |         type="radio"
  276 |         name="tabs"
> 277 |         {index === 0 ? checked : ""}
      |          ^
  278 |       />
  279 |       <label for={"tab" + index}>{tab}</label>
  280 |     </React.Fragment>
```

Is there a way to fix it or have a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`.

So you could do this:

```
defaultChecked={index===0}
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked` with no embellishments is a shortcut for `checked={true}`. To make it sometimes true and sometimes false, you can do:

```
  name="tabs"
  checked={index===0}
/>
```

Comment: It gave me the effect I want (the first tab is displayed by default) but it seems the other tabs have been disabled since they don't display their content. The other tabs receive "checked={false}" which makes them not clickable.